# True or false - Function analytic in bounded domain is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

If a function is analytic in a bounded domain then it is bounded. 
True or false. Why.

Comment: if it's analytic in the bounded domain then it is analytic where?????

Comment: @IttayWeiss corrected. thanks.

Comment: not quite Ittaly ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Think about the function $f(z) = \dfrac1z$.

Answer (score 0):

Can a function $f$ be analytic inside a bounded domain $\Omega$ and still have a pole $z_0$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ of $\Omega$?

Answer (score 0):

No, those are the kind of functions in which you can set the radius of convergence to the distance to the bound of the domain. A not so trivial example is $\log(\cos(z))$. It is analytic in the disc $D(0;R=\pi/2)$, but it's not bounded in that domain (it has an asymptote when $z$ goes to $\pi/2$ on the real axis.